# Using AWS OpsWorks, how do I start my node application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, recipe

I've created a simple stack in AWS OpsWorks consisting of a Node app server Layer and an Elastic Load Balancer -- I'm trying to get my application to kick off on the deploy life cycle event.  In other words, at some point I need the server to run `node start`

I have the built-in Chef recipes, summarized by life-cycle event below:

**Setup**: opsworks_nodejs

**Configure**: opsworks_nodejs::configure

**Deploy**: opsworks_nodejs, deploy::nodejs

But when I SSH into my instance and check for running node processes, nothing comes up.  I'm diving into the individual recipes now, but would appreciate any help or guidance on this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running with default OpsWorks Chef recipes, you must make sure that your main app file is named ***server.js*** and it's listening on ports 80 or 443.

See here for additional information - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinglayers-node.html